# Duda con correspondencia entre arreglos y punteros en C++

Tags: c++

De nuevo...

Me disculpo por preguntar dos veces seguidas, en realidad antes de preguntar de nuevo, me tome la molestia de googlear mucho. Pero realmente sentí que se contradecían las cosas, así que decido volver a preguntar, pero repito.. siento preguntar dos veces seguidas.

Bueno, el código es el siguiente:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int numeros[] = {1,5,9,7,4,3};
    int *dir_numeros;

    dir_numeros = &numeros[0]; // Tambien, por simplicidad podemos colocar 'numeros', en lugar de '&numeros[0]'

    for(int i=0; i < 6; i++){
        cout<<*dir_numeros++;
    }

    /*
    cout<<*dir_numeros;
    dir_numeros++;
    cout<<*dir_numeros;
    */

    return 0;
}
```

Tanto lo que esta comentado, como el for que esta en el main, me imprimen lo siguiente:

> 159743

Lo que estoy haciendo, es simplemente mostrar los valores del arreglo, pero esta vez, haciendo uso de punteros.

Para no hacer esto tan largo, la duda de acuerdo a lo anterior es la siguiente:

```
int numero = 5;
int *dir_numero = &numero;

cout<<*dir_numero; //Esto imprime el valor
cout<<dir_numero;  //Esto imprime la dirección de memoria de la variable a la que apunta
```

Teniendo eso claro, como es posible que en el for se use el ++ "de incremento" y este me imprima los valores del array?, es decir... Si uno se fija, ahí se esta usando el *, por lo que debería incrementar en uno dicho valor (1++) "porque la dirección que almaceno es la del primer elemento del array, por eso el 1".

En cambio, si vemos lo que esta comentado, es algo que hice yo, que funciona igual, pero que para mi tiene lógica. Porque esta vez lo que incremento es la dirección de memoria a la que apunta el puntero (mas que incrementar, es como seguir a la siguiente dirección de memoria, pues un arreglo almacena los datos de forma contigua, y claro... ahora sí recorrería el arreglo lógicamente.

entonces:

¿Porque el for hace lo mismo que lo que esta comentado, si este lo que incrementa es el valor del arreglo y no su dirección de memoria?

Muchas gracias, y perdón por extenderme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primero que nada, debemos comprender como funciona el [operador post-incremento](https://yosoy.dev/como-funciona-el-operador-de-post-incremento-y-post-decremento/).

**Ejemplo:**

```c
int i = 10;
cout << i++;
```

En este ejemplo se imprime el valor actual de la variable `i` y luego se incrementa `i`.

En pocas palabras, el operador post-incremento tomará el **valor actual de la variable** y luego **incrementará en `1` la variable.**

Ahora, modificaré un poco el código que agregaste en la pregunta y lo pondré así:

```c
int main()
{
    int numeros[] = {1,5,9,7,4,3};
    int *dir_numeros;

    dir_numeros = &numeros[0]; 

    for(int i=0; i < 6; i++)
        cout<< *dir_numeros++;

    dir_numeros = numeros;
    cout << endl;
    for(int i=0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        cout<<*dir_numeros;
        dir_numeros++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Ambos bucles nos dan el mismo resultado:

```c
159743
159743
```

Lo que nos interesa es este bloque:

```c
for(int i=0; i < 6; i++)
   cout<< *dir_numeros++;
```

Aquí debemos aplicar el mismo concepto que habíamos visto antes. Imprimimos el valor actual al que apunte el puntero `dir_numeros` y luego incrementamos en `1` la variable (que básicamente es el puntero).

Esto significa que en cada iteración el contenido del puntero va cambiando, pero esto sucede después de imprimir el valor.

Para que quede más claro, miremos este ejemplo:

```c
void print(int value)
{
    cout<< value;
}

int main(){
    int numeros[] = {1,5,9,7,4,3};
    int *dir_numeros;

    dir_numeros = &numeros[0]; 

    for(int i=0; i < 6; i++)
        print(*dir_numeros++);

    return 0;
}
```

En cada iteración accedemos al contenido de la variable al que apunte el puntero y se la pasamos al parámetro `value` y luego, incrementamos el puntero para que apunte a otro elemento del arreglo.

Respondiendo a esta pregunta:

> > ¿Porque el for hace lo mismo que lo que esta comentado, si este lo que incrementa es el valor del arreglo y no su dirección de memoria?

Lo que está en el bucle for no incrementa el valor del arreglo, sino, el contenido del puntero, pero esto pasa después (por eso el operador se llama **post-incremento**) de acceder al valor actual de la variable.

Para incrementar el valor del arreglo, se debería de usar el **operador pre-incremento**.

**Ejemplo:**

```c
void print(int pValue)
{
    cout<< pValue;
}

int main()
{
    int numeros[] = {1,5,9,7,4,3};
    int *dir_numeros;

    dir_numeros = &numeros[0]; 

    for(int i=0; i < 6; i++)
        print(++*dir_numeros);

    return 0;
}
```

Resultado por pantalla:

```c
234567
```

Si te das cuenta, en cada iteración antes de tomar el valor actual, incrementamos el contenido al que apunte el puntero y luego le pasamos al parámetro `value` el valor actual (este es el nuevo valor incrementado) de la variable (en este caso es el espacio de memoria donde se guarda el primer elemento del *array*). Pero la diferencia de este código con el otro, es que en ningún momento actualizamos el contenido del puntero, por lo tanto, **siempre** apuntará al primer elemento del arreglo.